# Adding autocomplete to dynamic textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

which contains Initially  a row with single textbox and i added auto complete  functionality to the textbox it works fine . Then i added some more textboxes by using javascript now i want to add the autocomplete functionality to the newly created textbox .  please help me to add the autocomplete to the newly creted textbox

my code for auto complete is

```
<script>
 $( ".productcode" ).autocomplete({ 
        minLength: 0,
           source: BASEURL1 + "sales/searchCustomer1/",
                    //source:projects1,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
             $( ".productcode" ).val( ui.item.label);

                        //   var id= $(this).attr('id');
                        //     $( id ).val( ui.item.label);  
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
                        //alert($(this).attr('id')); 
             $( "#product-code1" ).val( ui.item.label);
                              $( "#product-id1" ).val( ui.item.prod_id);
             $( "#product-name1" ).val( ui.item.prod_name);
                              $( "#product-mrp1" ).val( ui.item.mrp);
              $( "#product-price1" ).val( ui.item.sales_rate);


        }
    })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>Code:" + item.label + "<br>Name:" +
                                item.prod_name + ",MRP:"+  item.mrp+   ",Rate:" + item.sales_rate +  ",STk:" +item.stk +"</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul ); 
    };
});
```

code for generating new textbox like
       
           function addRow(tableID) {

```
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "text";
    element1.id = "product-code"+(rowCount + 1);
    element1.name="product-code["+(rowCount + 1)+"]";
    element1.setAttribute('class','productcode'); 
         element1.setAttribute('style','width:100px; float:none');
       $("#product-code1").autocomplete({ });
        cell1.appendChild(element1);
        </script>
```

my form is 
    
            
               code
               id
               name
               mrp
               price

```
       <tr>
    <td> <input type="text" id="product-code1" name="productcode[1]" class="productcode" style="width:100px;float:none"/></td>
    <td> <input type="text" id="product-id1" name="product-id[1]" readonly="readonly" style="width:100px;float:none"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="product-name1" name="product-name[1]"  readonly="readonly" style="width:100px;float:none"/></td>
   <td> <input type="text" id="product-mrp1" name="product-mrp[1]"  readonly="readonly" style="width:100px;float:none"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="product-price1" name="product-price[1]"  readonly="readonly" style="width:100px;float:none"/></td>

   <td width="10%"  align="left" nowrap="nowrap">
    <input type="button" style="display:none" name="btndelete" id="btnadd" class="blueBoxpsd" onClick="deleteRow1('dataTable','0')" value="delete"></td>
   <td> <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="chk0" style="display:none"/></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: what is the error?? and please make a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.fn.CreateAutocomplete = function(){
   $(this).autocomplete({ 
        minLength: 0,
           source: BASEURL1 + "sales/searchCustomer1/",
                    //source:projects1,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
             $(this).val( ui.item.label);

                        //   var id= $(this).attr('id');
                        //     $( id ).val( ui.item.label);  
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
                        //alert($(this).attr('id')); 
             $( "#product-code1" ).val( ui.item.label);
                              $( "#product-id1" ).val( ui.item.prod_id);
             $( "#product-name1" ).val( ui.item.prod_name);
                              $( "#product-mrp1" ).val( ui.item.mrp);
              $( "#product-price1" ).val( ui.item.sales_rate);


        }
    })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>Code:" + item.label + "<br>Name:" +
                                item.prod_name + ",MRP:"+  item.mrp+   ",Rate:" + item.sales_rate +  ",STk:" +item.stk +"</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul ); 
    };
});
```

and then create autocompete in addRow function like that

```
$(element1).CreateAutocomplete();
```

you have to change something in function for works :)

Comment: if i changed my auto complete function to  
  jquery("product-code1").CreateAutoComplete();
  jquery.fn.CreateAutocomplete =                          $(function() { 
 $(this).autocomplete({  });                      
add my dynamic element call to autocomplete like $(element1).CreateAutoComplete(); now my initial autocomplete also not working

Comment: `jQuery.fn.CreateAutocomplete`  **not jquery**

Comment: jQuery("productcode").CreateAutocomplete(auto);
   var auto =  jQuery.fn.CreateAutocomplete =  $(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({  .... i got an error jQuery(".productcode").CreateAutocomplete is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

jQuery(".productcode").CreateAutocomplete(auto);

Comment: your function wrong. look my answer carefully not `jQuery.fn.CreateAutoComplete = $(function(){});`

Comment: $(".productcode").CreateAutoComplete();
   jQuery.fn.CreateAutocomplete =      $(function() {
       $(this).autocomplete({}); $(".productcode").CreateAutoComplete is not a function
  

$(".productcode").CreateAutoComplete();

Comment: look notation carefully :(((( `$(".productcode").createAutocomplete()` not **AutoComplete**

Comment: i cant get you  $('.productcode').CreateAutocomplete();

         jQuery.fn.CreateAutocomplete =      $(function() {...} is not working

Comment: $(function() {
                     
                   
    $(".productcode").live("keypress", function() {
                          var id= $(this).attr('id');
                       id=id.replace("product-code","");
                $("#product-code"+id).autocomplete({ })

Answer (score 0):

use this.it works

```
$('body').delegate(".class name", "focusin", function () {
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("your method where is ur list","controller name")',

            minLength: 1,

            select: function (evt, ui) {

                alert("label"+ui.item.label);
                alert("id" + ui.item.id);


        });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

this whole code is for dynamicaly created textboxes with autocomplete functionality

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;



    $("#lnkAddProduct").on("click", function () {


        var d = '<div class="addedProduct "><div class="control-group " style="margin-bottom:10px;"><input type="text" class="ProductName span2 pull-left" id="Product_Name_' + i + '" name="Product_Name" value="" placeholder="start typing to load products" )"/><input type="hidden" class="ProductId" name="Product_Id" id="Product_Id_' + i + '" value="" /><a href="#" class="clsremove font-midium" style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:5px;" id="remove_' + i + '">remove</a></div></div>';
        $('#ProductList').append(d);
        alert("newID:"+i);

        $(".clsremove").unbind("click").click(function () {
            $(this).closest(".addedProduct").remove();
        });


       $('body').delegate(".ProductName", "focusin", function () {
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("NewvendorList","Product")',
              // source: '@Url.Action("your method where is ur list","controller name")',
            minLength: 1,

            select: function (evt, ui) {

                alert("label"+ui.item.label);
                alert("id" + ui.item.id);

        });
        });

        i = i + 1;          
    });


});
```

and this is code for view

```
 <div class="span10" style="margin-left:0px;">
                <a href="#" id="lnkAddProduct" style="font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;margin-right:10px;margin-left:30px;">Add Product</a>

            </div>
```